# Contract Violation; expected: real?; given #f

Tags: scheme

I'm sorry if this question has been answered before, but I've looked around and I can't really understand the explanation as to why I'm getting this error.

From what I understand I'm asking if a statement is true and then if it is I'm asking it to return an expression. And apparently I'm not allowed to get #t/#f answers and expressions? I'm not sure. Could someone help me understand.

This is my code.

```
(define (piecewise x)
  (define pi 3.142)
  (cond
    ((> x (* pi 2)) (- x (* 2 pi)))
    ((or ( > x (* pi -1) (= x ( * -1 pi)))) (sin x))
    ((or ( < x (* 2 pi)) (= x (* 2 pi))) (sin x))
    (else (- (- 1 x) pi))))
```

Comment: Misplaced parentheses in the first `or`. (It has only one argument, which is a comparison of `x`, `(* pi -1)`. and `(= x ...`.)

Comment: Also,  `>=` and `<=` exist. You don't need to complicate things like that.

Comment: After adding a binding for x and running in DrRacket (#lang typed/racket) the error message is `Type Checker: type mismatch- expected: Real given: Boolean in: (= x (* -1 pi))` which shows exactly where the problem is: `(= x (* -1 pi))` produces a Boolean, but the context is attempting to compare it with a Real.

Comment: More explicitly, you wrote `(or (> x y (= z w)))` instead of `(or (> x y) (= z w))`. (Comparisons take an arbitrary number of arguments.)

Comment: If you are using `(* 2 pi)` as often as you are, you might want to add `(define tau (* 2 pi))` to reduce redundancy and improve clarity.

Answer (score 0):

If I may, if we take all of the suggestions and use them to simplify the code a bit, we might get the following:

```
(define (piecewise x)
  (let* ((pi 3.142)
         (tau (* 2 pi)))
    (cond
     ((> x tau) 
      (- x tau))
     ((or (>= x (- pi))
          (<= x tau))
      (sin x))
     (else (+ x pi)))))
```

This runs without errors under both Racket and Guile. Whether it computes the function correctly, only the OP can say for certain.